# Azure Service Bus throwing MessageLockLostException for non-partitioned queue when lock duration has not passed

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm trying to receive a message using the `PeekLock` receive mode, process the message (the processing time is well below message lock duration), and then complete the message. I've checked all around for others having similar issues but I think I have ruled out all proposed solutions.

- The queue is *not* partitioned.
- There is only one message on the queue when I'm testing and I've even tried to set `PrefetchCount` to 1 anyway.
- There is only one receiver active.
- I've increased the `LockDuration` to 5 minutes and the processing time is ~20 seconds. When inspecting the received message I can see that the `LockedUntil` property is much later than the `CompleteAsync` call.

Even so, when calling the `CompleteAsync` method I get the `MessageLockLostException` every time.

This is (the relevant part of) the wrapper class I'm using:

```
public class ServiceBusClient
{
    private readonly ServiceBusConnectionManager manager;

    public ServiceBusClient(string connectionString)
    {
        manager = new ServiceBusConnectionManager(connectionString);
    }

    public async Task<Message> GetNextDownlinkMessage(string queueName)
    {
        var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(manager.Connection, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
        var message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
        await messageReceiver.CloseAsync();
        return message;
    }

    public async Task Complete(string queueName, string lockToken)
    {
        var queueClient = new QueueClient(manager.Connection, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null);
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(lockToken);
    }
}
```

I've checked that the `lockToken` is actually the one set on the received message. I'm really running out of ideas.

---

Edit: I later realized that the error is because I instantiate a new `MessageReceiver` object each time and the message needs to be completed by the exact same instance used to fetch the message.

Comment: Best to provide a link to a repository with the simple reproduction of this issue. This sounds very much off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Every time I completed a message I created a new `QueueClient` instance. It turns out that you need to complete or abandon the message using the exact same `MessageReceiver` instance that received it. You can't create a new instance of `MessageReceiver` even if the queue is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're using an older version of the Service Bus SDK. There's a newer version that's coming out end of this month for general availability--you can find it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus)

With the new library, you can complete a message by calling `.CompleteMessageAsync(msg)` on a `SeviceBusReceiver` ([sample link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus#complete-a-message)):

```
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
string queueName = "<queue_name>";
// since ServiceBusClient implements IAsyncDisposable we create it with "await using"
await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

// create a receiver that we can use to receive and settle the message
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName);

// the received message is a different type as it contains some service set properties
ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

// complete the message, thereby deleting it from the service
await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(receivedMessage);
```

Comment: I added more context to the code and I've also answered my own question. With this new SDK, is it still required to complete the message using the same `MessageReceiver` instance or is it fine to create new instances as long as `lockToken` is correct?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @Hannes Johansson. You have to complete a message using the receiver that received the message. This is because the lock token is tracked by the service in the context of the entity that the message was sent to. In the eyes of the service, each ServiceBusReceiver is a new entity.

Comment: Right, thanks for the explanation. So my issue was that I was creating new ServiceBusReceivers all the time.